# I have a water line to my fridge with no shut off valve

Tags: refrigerator

Is it hard to add one or even something to cap off the end?  I removing the whole refrigerator and won't be using that line. I may want to use it in the future so I don't want to remove it.

Comment: Are you sure there is no shutoff?  Have you located where the line originates from?  What kind of pipe/tubing is it?

Comment: I would look for at least a saddle valve if not connected to a proper valve under your sink that’s were most fridges hook up that I have seen, sometimes a saddle valve in the crawl space.